# The workflow version is not working based on the new version after changing

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow

On changing the SharePoint version fom 3.3 to 4.2, the previous workflows are not working with the version 4.2 and the project template is also not changed.

Can you please help me fix this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are the version numbers from? SharePoint is usually listed by year, 2013,2016 or four part version number 15.0.5259.1001, etc.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about this issue? What does the “changing version” actually mean? Have you recently applied an update or upgraded SharePoint to a higher version (like from 2013 to 2016)? And we will need extra information about the “project template” as well.